# Update single character in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to update only one character after _

I have column value ABC123_169876357 and want to replace value after "*" like 
ABC123***3**69876357.

I have used below function

```
replace(substr('ABC123_169876357',8,1),1,3)
```

But it is just replacing value but I want to update value after "_"

Could anyone please help me to update?

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating the table, you can use:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
SET FIELD_NAME =
(SUBSTR(FIELD_NAME, 1, instr(FIELD_NAME,'_')-1) 
|| '**3**' 
|| substr(FIELD_NAME, instr(FIELD_NAME,'_')+2))

WHERE FIELD_NAME = 'ABC123_169876357'
```

Replace TABLE_NAME with your table name and FIELD_NAME with corresponding field name.

Comment: Thank you for the provided Solution. But as I want to update char. after "_", using above query It omits "_" so I have change -1 to +0 and its working find

Answer (score 2):

Like wolφi, I would also use REGEXP_REPLACE, but probably something more generic like:

```
with test_data as (
  select 'ABC123_169876357' str from dual
)
select str, regexp_replace(str,'_.','**3**') new_str
from test_data;

STR                  NEW_STR             
-------------------- --------------------
ABC123_169876357     ABC123**3**69876357
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use REGEXP_REPLACE for that:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('ABC123_169876357', '(ABC123).*(69876357)','\1xxx\2') FROM DUAL;

ABC123xxx69876357
```

would that solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

This may be done by combination of `substr` and `instr`:

```
with test_data as (
  select 'ABC123_169876357' str from dual
)
select 
  (
    substr(str, 1, instr(str,'_')-1)    -- get beginning of string up to '_' char
      || '**3**'                        -- concatenate with replacement string
      || substr(str, instr(str,'_')+2)  -- add rest of string
   ) as result_string   
from test_data
```